# android service stops working after application is not in use for awhile

Tags: android, service

I have a service for my application that runs fine, but when a user is not using there phone for while like 20 minutes the service just doesnt work any more. is there something i suppose to be doing like saving a state or something, i am lost at this point. I dont see why the service doest keep running, I look in the application>running services on my phone and it still says its running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem few time back. Then I started to use Android Alarm Service. That solved my problem. Here is a reference link http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: This. Don't create long running services. Android is free to kill them at will

Comment: I am going to try this but how did it help you?

Comment: I need to fetch network parameters and post them on server periodically for which I implemented the timertask. now when the device gets ideal/screen lock it stop functioning... then I got this Alarm service as functional solution.

Comment: Had the same problem with services, that for periods of time, I needed to fetch data and update in backgound, but the service always stopped after some hours. I will try to use first WAKE_LOCK to see how that works with the service, and after that try your suggestion for AlarmManager. Looks like that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep running in the background (e.g. downloading something), you need to grab a wakelock (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Also, look at the following if you happen to do downloads in the background:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting()

Comment: this will affect the battery performance badly and drain out it very soon.

Comment: You can keep running in the background for pretty long if you don't keep the display on. The battery is drained mostly by the display not the CPU. But it's true that you should only grab a wakelock if you really need to, like downloading, logging sensor data, etc.

Comment: @SzabolcsBerecz  i have used wake lock as well but it still my service stops working after sometime

Answer (score 4):

You can use Broadcast receiver instead to use like service.
And it can be called same as Service with alarm manager.
Receiver:

```
public class CallListReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Call List receiver called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    }
}
```

You can continuously call it using:

```
public void startAlert(Context context) {
Intent call_intent = new Intent(this, CallListReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingCallIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, call_intent, 0);
    AlarmManager call_alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    call_alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), (7 * 1000), pendingCallIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This Android's behavior that A Service has maximum life of 20 minutes. After 20 Minutes, it will be automatically killed by Android OS. But i think that there is a solution. i dont have tested it yet. The Solution is:
In your onStartCommand(), put this code at the end of this method 
`return START_STICKY;`

Comment: Where did you find "A Service has maximum life of 20 minutes." ?